# Find and copy files in batch with keeping the original structure

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, window, cmd, findstr

I need to find all *.PST file on my "C" drive, and copy all instance to a new folder on C:\

How to do this in dos-batch with keep the original structure? I don't want to override the second instance the first one..

- I think this should work, but I need to keep the original subdirectory or take every hit to a unique subdirectory?
- I have to exclude the c:\backuppst directory from search

```
 for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d *.PST') do copy /b "%%~i" "C:\backuppst"
```

### Edit

As you suggested I use Xcopy:

Xcopy c:*.pst c:\backuppst /i/h/s/y /Exclude:my.txt

In my.txt I have: C:\backuppst

But I got "cannot preform cycling copy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you if there are no PST files under c:\backuppst to begin with.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d \*.PST') do xcopy "%%~i" "c:\backuppst%%~pi"
pause
```

Comment: After run this snippet, i got error messages. Cannot create file when that file already exists ....the directory created, but the file did not copied

Comment: @holian I tested and edited the code above with some sample files.  Try it now.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d c:\*.PST^|findstr /ivc:"C:\backuppst"') do copy /b "%%~fi" "C:\backuppst"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `xcopy` command, it can do this in one go, without needing `for`.

It supports the parameter `/exclude`, which lets you exclude specific files or folders, like your backup directory.

Comment: i try what u suggested, but i got circular error. If i try xcopy only for a directory, than work

Comment: Since you're copying pst files, you should exclude those. The mask is already *.pst, so no need to exclude my.txt. I think your command should be something like `xcopy c:\*.pst c:\backuppst\ /s/i/h/y /exclude:c:\backuppst` to prevent copying the contents of `c:\backuppst` to itself.

Comment: `/exclude:` refers to a file only.  It needs to be a text file with something like c:\backuppst\\*.* or c:\backuppst\ inside it.